# User password in DXL - Dialog Box

Tags: text, dialog, passwords, hide, ibm-doors

I need to enter a password in a DXL program. I have seen that there are some functions to do this (`createPasswordDialog` or `confirmPasswordDialog` are some), but what I would be interested in would be to show a normal dialog box (`field`) but with the encrypted characters, that is, not to show them or show the typical "*".

Is ther any way to do it? Thanks for the help

)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not seen this - but perhaps you can use the perm `setTextChangeCB` which will be triggered every time that a key is pressed - but I think it will be triggered only after the pressed character is shown. So you could implement a behaviour like "every time a user presses a key, add this to the stored password and replace the content of the field itself with an appropriate number of asterisks" (but you will have to find a solution for the backspace key)

Comment: Thanks for the help, but how can I have a "normal" password form (that encrypts the characters you write) in the same DBE of the dialog Box?

Comment: Not sure if I understood the remark correctly, but `setTextChangeCB` is a callback routine that is set for a specific DBE, not for the complete DB. So, you would have something like `void myPasswordRoutine (DBE field) {...}; DB dialog=create; DBE txtUserName = field (dialog, "User Name"); DBE txtPassword = field (dialog, "Password"); setTextChangeCB (txtPassword, myPasswordRoutine)`

Comment: (sorry, I could not change my remark any more. Instead of `void myPasswordRoutine (DBE field)…` you must use another variable name than "field", since this is a reserved keyword.)

Comment: For example, in the next code, how i can do it? This function changes the Password characters by "+" character only in the DXL Interaction, not in the DBE txtPassword (in the DB).

void myPasswordRoutine(DBE txtPassword) {string hello = plainText( get txtPassword );print "+";}

DB dialog = create("Hello World", styleCentered | styleStandard);DBE txtUserName = field (dialog, "User Name", "", 34, false);DBE txtPassword = field (dialog, "Password", "", 34, false);setTextChangeCB (txtPassword, myPasswordRoutine);show dialog;